# Can't open a mongo connection

Tags: database, windows, mongodb, repair

I'm using Windows and never had a problem with mongo before but now all a sudden I cannot open a connection.

First I'd like to say that I have spent the past 2 hours trying to solve this issue.  I have tried everything I was able to find on this issue on stack overflow, nothing has worked so far.

When I run `mongod` in a terminal I get this, (Only the bottom half of the message for brevity)

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.769-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.776-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":7}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.776-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22281,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.777-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.777-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T19:33:50.777-05:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":62}}
```

What I tried already.

I have tried running `mongod --repair`, it didn't work.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing mongo.  The newly installed version is a later version, 4.4.1.  My previous version I believe was 3.6.

One post on here said to delete the data folder and replace it.
I deleted the folder along with everything inside of it and created a new data folder, however the new data folder is completely empty, I'm not sure if that is a problem.

Since doing that I have run `mongod --repair`

Here is the location of the data folder.
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\data

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Advice: Pay attention to the logs. By pruning the first part, you cut off the error, and that snippet is useless. Then, be aware that `mongod --repair` isn't a good option.

Comment: Thanks, I figured the most important part was the last bit that shows the exit code.  I got this figured out now so all is well.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, but surely the "F" line, which includes the failure message would complete it. ( It's not useless, i should correct myself, but it's not complete. ) Alright good to hear that is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in windows services whether it is running or not.
If not, start it manually.

[image]

Comment: If nothing works, watch this video. This can help you.      
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwMwO8pXfq0&t=696s

Comment: Thanks for that.  It seems that I don't need to have mongod running in order to connect to mongo anymore.  I don't know if that is something that changed in the new version but my problem seems to have gone away now.

Answer (score 0):

First close all terminal and delete the data(which contains db folder ie data/db) folder from your local drive and try to run again mongod command